# How to get proper hour from $filter in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have input:

```
Tue Apr 15 2014 18:00:28 GMT+0300 (IDT)
```

When I try to run filter:

```
var currDate = $filter('date')(new Date(date), 'dd-MM-yyyy h:mm');
```

I get:

```
"15-04-2014 6:00"
```

In input hour is `18` but I get `6`

Here is a <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1222/)</kbd> that demonstrates the problem.

Thanks,

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it to use the 24 hour clock, so instead of h  use HH.  Documented [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/date-filter-in-angularjs/)